# Insert Row in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, insertion, datawindow

Actually I need to validate empty columns in a newly inserted row in a DataWindow control. I tried with ItemFocusChanged event script is as follow

```
if dwo.name="emp_name" then
    if dw_1.GetItemString(row,"emp_no")= '' then
        MessageBox("E-Ledger","Enter Employee Number")
        dw_1.SetColumn("emp_no")
    end if
end if
```

but it was not happening. While saving I tried with

```
if dw_1.GetItemString(ll_row,"emp_no")= '' then
    MessageBox("E-Ledger","Enter Employee Number")
    dw_1.SetColumn("emp_no")
    return
end if
```

this is also not happening.
Kindly help me to validate while ItemFocusChanged and while saving for newly inserted row.
Thank you friends.....
PVP

Answer (score 0):

The ItemFocusChanged event won't get triggered when you call `InsertRow()`, because `InsertRow()` doesn't change the current row.  You can call [`SetRow()`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37783.1250/html/dwref/CCJDFFCD.htm) to make it the current row, or [`ScrollToRow()`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37783.1250/html/dwref/CCJBHFDGdw.htm) to both make it the current row and scroll it into view.

The logical place for validation is the `itemchanged` event normally.  This will be triggered when a column loses focus or manually with the [`AcceptText()`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37783.1250/html/dwref/CAIDFCBI.htm) function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that ItemFocusChanged is the wrong event to test this validation in, because if I click past the emp_no field, this logic will never execute.

You haven't mentioned any save script observations from debugging that might narrow things down, but as a wild guess, I'd guess that the actual value of emp_no at this point is NULL (the NilIsNull attribute on the column, maybe), which won't pass the test you've programmed. You'd want something more like

```
ls_Value = dw_1.GetItemString(ll_row,"emp_no")
if (ls_Value = '') or IsNull (ls_Value) then
...
```

Not that this would handle you putting spaces in this field, but you can probably handle that, if that is the requirement.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's better to validate required fields just before saving. We have to allow user to move focus from an empty required fields - maybe, the user wants to populate it later, after filling other fields.
2. Required fields validation is very common task. It should be performed by the framework automatically, with no need to write the checking for each field.
3. If you still want to validate empty mandatory fields on focus change then it's better to code the ItemFocusChanging script, not ItemFocusChanged.